# How do I change some of the syntax colors in the Visual Studio IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax, ide

I've been looking around on some people who code and some of them have colored syntaxes..
Such as the person in this picture.

[image]

And I've been trying to figure out how to change the colors but I really couldnt find any good docs about it.
How do I change the syntax color in Visual Studio?

Comment: What version of VS? I would think that syntax highlighting would be enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

[This is Microsoft's guide for setting syntax highlighting.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265717(v=vs.60).aspx)